# Finding the last 10 digits of 2^n

Tags: c, unsigned-long-long-int

So i'm supposed to find out the last 10 digits of 2^n(0<=n<=100) where n is the input. I found a method to handle large numbers but the program fails when n>64. Any leads on how to go about with this would be appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


/* Iterative Function to calculate (x^y)%p in O(log y) */
int power(long long int x, long long int y, long long int p)
{
long long int res = 1; // Initialize result

x = x % p; // Update x if it is more than or
// equal to p

while (y > 0) {

    // If y is odd, multiply x with result
    if (y & 1)
        res = (res * x) % p;

    // y must be even now
    y = y >> 1; // y = y/2
    x = (x * x) % p;
}
return res;
}

// C function to print last 10 digits of a^b
void printLastDigits(long long int a,long long int b)
{    

long long int temp = pow(10,10);

// Calling modular exponentiation
temp = power(a, b, temp);

if (temp)
    printf("%d",temp);
}

int main()
{
long long int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
printLastDigits(2,n);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a test of your observational skills. You're probably being expected to find patterns (as there is a pattern) and apply your knowledge to extrapolate  (so you don't need to calculate `2^n`).

Comment: The idea of using modpow works, however your modpow does not work, due to the infamous "early overflow" of `x * x` (and `res * x`), before you get a chance to reduce it modulo `p`.

Comment: @harold So is there a way around that?

Comment: An easy way is to multiply 1 by 2, n times while discarding digits above the last 10. You could also find a pattern for each of the 10 last digits in powers of 2, but it involves carries.

Comment: For `n <= 100` exponentiation by squaring is not that critical, you can easily multiply by 2^20 (max 5 steps, so still very fast) without premature overflow

Comment: You could use a string of max 10 digits and miltiply each digit (using carry) in the string with 2 each time.

Comment: Using `unsigned long long` math is sufficient to solve this task.   No need for int128, bignum nor strings.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer archive for programming problems, not a code-writing service for lazy people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* to worry about the 'high' bits, since multiplication by `2` *left shifts* them out of range of the lower part of the product you're interesting in. Just be sure you're using the `unsigned long long` type (of at least 64 bits) to hold integral types that are wide enough, e.g.,

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void low_digits (unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned long long base = 2, modulus = 10000000000ULL;

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "2^%u mod 10^10 = %llu\n", i, base);
        base = (base * 2) % modulus;
    }
}
```

You can test `2^1000` with a bignum calculator:

10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703\
51051124936122493198378815695858127594672917553146825187145285692314\
04359845775746985748039345677748242309854210746050623711418779541821\
53046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660\
429831652624386837205668069376

while `n = 1000` above yields: 5668069376

---

Others have noted, that this is a `naive` method, and modular exponentiation is far more efficient for sufficiently large values of `(n)`. Unfortunately, this is going to require products that exceed the range of an unsigned 64-bit value, so unless you're prepared to implement `[hi64][lo64]` multi-precision mul / mod operations, it's probably beyond the scope of your task.

Fortunately, later versions of gcc and clang do provide an extended 128 bit integral type:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void low_digits (unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned long long base = 2, modulus = 10000000000ULL;
    __extension__ unsigned __int128 u = 1, w = base;

    while (n != 0)
    {
        if ((n & 0x1) != 0)
            u = (u * w) % modulus; /* (mul-reduce) */

        if ((n >>= 1) != 0)
            w = (w * w) % modulus; /* (sqr-reduce) */
    }

    base = (unsigned long long) u;
    fprintf(stdout, "2^%u mod 10^10 = %llu\n", n, base);
}
```

Comment: This is the basic iteration method, times x each time.

Comment: This works slightly better if you cast to 128bit for the multiplication, and then let it go back to 64bit again - that way the compiler uses a faster 64x64->128 multiplication instead of a 128x128->128 multiplication (wasting multiplications on the upper halves, which are zero)

Comment: @harold - true, but I think it's better to show the mod-exp algorithm without excessive casting. I don't think the compiler is smart enough to know that successive division always fits in a word, however, and the run-time is dominated by a call to something like `__umodti3` - e.g., you don't get a simple `divq` instruction on x86-64.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses strings to perform the multiplication:

```
void lastdigits(char digits[11], int n)
{
    int i, j, x, carry;
    for (i=0; i<n;i++) {
        for (j=9, carry=0; j>=0; j--) {
            x= digits[j]-'0';
            x *= 2;
            x += carry;
            if (x>9) {carry= 1; x -= 10;}
            else carry= 0;
            digits[j]= x+'0';
        }
    }
}

void test(void)
{
    char digits[11];

    strcpy(digits,"0000000001");
    lastdigits(digits,10);
    printf("%s\n",digits);

    strcpy(digits,"0000000001");
    lastdigits(digits,20);
    printf("%s\n",digits);

    strcpy(digits,"0000000001");
    lastdigits(digits,100);
    printf("%s\n",digits);
}
```

Output:

```
0000001024
0001048576
6703205376
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea of using the string. Did'nt even think of that.

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers you've received don't actually show what you're doing wrong:

> ```
> x = (x * x) % p;
> ```

You're assuming that `x * x` still fits in `long long int`. But if `x` is `0x100000000` (4294967296, for 10 decimal digits) and `long long int` is 64 bits, then it will not fit.

Either:

You need a way to accurately multiply two arbitrary 10-digit numbers. The result may have 20 digits and may not fit in `long long int` or even `unsigned long long int`. This means you'd need to use some bigint library or implement something like that yourself.

Or:

You need to avoid multiplying multiple possibly-10-digit numbers.

The answer you've accepted opts for simple repeated multiplication by `2`. This is sufficient for your problem now, but beware that this does significantly increase the complexity if you want to allow very large exponents.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are finding the last digit of 2^n, you just need to consider last digit and ignore every other digit

```
1. 2*2 = 4
2. 4*2 = 8
3. 8*2 = 16 (ignore last-but-one digit i.e 1)
4. 6*2 = 12 (ignore last-but-one digit i.e 1)
5. 2*2 = 4
6. 4*2 = 8
7. 8*2 = 16 (ignore last-but-one digit i.e 1)
8. 6*2 = 12 (ignore last-but-one digit i.e 1)
9. 2*2 = 4

... n-1 iterations
```

To find the last 2 digits of 2^n, ignore all digits except last 2 digits.

```
1. 2*2 = 4
2. 4*2 = 8
3. 8*2 = 16
4. 16*2 = 32
5. 32*2 = 64
6. 64*2 = 128 (Consider last 2 digits)
7. 28*2 = 56
8. 56*2 = 112 (Consider last 2 digits)
9. 12*2 = 24

... n-1 iterations
```

Similarly, to find the last 10 digits of 2^n, consider just last 10 digits at each iteration and repeat it for `n-1` iterations.

**Note:**

With this approach, the biggest number you'll get during the calculation can be of 11 digits ~ 10^11, while for a 64-bit machine the max value is ~ 2^64 =  ~ 10^18